# Access data directories in a platform independant way in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm developing a corodva (phonegap) application and I'm saving some downloaded files to the data directory. Currently if I'm accessing the filesystem entry to the target file in the following way:

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("<filename>", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

I tried with `LocalFileSystem.APPLICATION` but it gives a javascript error.

In iOS the file gets saved into `/Documents/<filename>` , and in android into `/mnt/sdcard/<filename>`.

I want to store those files in `/data/data/<app>/<filename>` in Android and the equivalent in iOS (which I guess is `/Application Support/<filename>`).

Now the question is:

Is there a way to access these in a platform independent way so I don't need to add ifs to check in which platform I am?

Comment: Have a look at this question and its answer, might help you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361577/phonegap-file-download-to-device-which-device-path-to-take

Comment: @Chips_100 I'm already accessing the filesystem as that example which led me to the question I'm asking, I'll edit it to show this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up a small blog post to show how to move platform dependent paths out to a json file you load at startup. That way you don't have to do the clunky tests for what platform you are on.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/01/on-eleventh-day-of-phonegapping.html

Comment: @SimonMacDonld those are the kind of ifs I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: I don't do any ifs in the blog post. Look at the code, it is a way to get around having to do the if (ios) else if (android) etc.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your blog post, I think you could include the json file as some kind of "platform.js" in your index file instead of using XHR, It is a great solution but I was looking for one out of thebox, now I'm starting to think that there is no out of the box solution :)