# read a text file from sdcard and display using phone gap

Tags: android, cordova

I have example.txt file sdcard and I want to display it using phone gap.I am very new to android and phone gap please help.
Here is my example.txt file:

```
     <h2>This file is in sdcard</h2>
```

Here is my phonegap.java

```
    package com.example.phonegap;
    import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

     public class Phonegap extends DroidGap{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/myfile.html");
       }

    }
```

and here is the myfile.html in www:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
      <title>FileReader Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("file:///sdcard/example.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Read File</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try something? more people will be willing to help if they see you had put some effort..

Comment: i tried from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html but it didnot work...

Comment: i also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967696/writing-and-reading-file-in-phonegap

Comment: paste the code/logs(in case you see an error)

Comment: i dont see error but output is only the content written inside html body tag in myfile.html file www..which is file i have used.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("file:///sdcard/example.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

to be this:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("example.txt", {create: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

assuming that the file you want to read is "example.txt" and is located in the /sdcard folder.

Comment: there are no errors but i canot see the output..where can see the output please help!! i am using eclipse......

Comment: @SimonMacDonald, any idea how I could read a file off the internal memory when it defaults to /sdcard?

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem. I don't think the API document in Phonegap is right, so i referred *JavaScript:the definitive guide*, I found two key points:

1. the location of the file I am ready to read.
   --> I found the default parent path is : /mnt/sdcard. So "/mnt/sdcard/temp/test.txt" file was written as `fileSystem.root.getFile("temp/test.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail)`
2. after `reader.readAsText(file)`, just using `element.innerHTML = reader.result`  can't display the result in HTML file.
   so I add a callback:

   ```
   reader.onload = function(){
       element.innerHTML = reader.result
   }
   ```

After adjusting the two parts, my code works!

StackOverflow has very strict upload format policy, so I can't upload the exact code. But you can contact me to ask for the code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the example.txt is at the root of SD card(Not resides in a folder). Then change following of your code,

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("file:///sdcard/example.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }
```

to

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("example.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }
```

And try by using alert in the below function,

```
function readAsText(file) {
        alert("readAstext");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {


               console.log("Read as text");
                console.log(evt.target.result);
                alert("content : "+evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

If that is not work, please add below code to your body tag in HTML

```
 <body onload='onLoad();'>
```

Let me know issues you may faced.
Thanks,,