# How to write to a local file in js (phonegap) 

Tags: javascript, file, jquery-mobile, text

Hi I'm trying to write some text at local text file with `$.twFile.save` but the result is nothing. I try to write on an android device with my phonegap app.

I use the following code

```
     t.executeSql('SELECT * FROM flatmetric', [], 
      function(t, metric) {
       var mymetric = metric.rows.length;

       for (i = 0 ; i < mymetric ; i += 1) {
        var row = metric.rows.item(i);

          sendmetric += row.buildingcode;
          sendmetric += row.flatno; 

       $.twFile.save("file:///mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista/Collector.txt", sendmetric) ;
      }
     )
```

Where am I wrong?

Is there any other way to do this except twFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WebKit browsers twFile uses a Java applet, TiddlySaver.jar, to accomplish the filesystem interaction.  However, the WebView in Android is not capable of using this or any Java applets.

Instead try the phonegap file API:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

See StackOverflow: 
[Writing and reading file in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967696/writing-and-reading-file-in-phonegap)